# удаление элементов с массива больше заданого значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
nums=[1,2,55,2,6,969,44,65,21,45,44,42,10,72,12,35,2,0,512,3,410,30]
for i in nums:
    if i>30:
        nums.remove(i)
print(nums)
```

Задача кода удалить все элементы,которые больше 30 и вывести готовый список на экран.
Но вместо того, чтобы вернуть [1,2,2,6,21,10,12,2,0,3] она возвращает [1,2,2,6,44,21,44,10,12,2,0,3,30]

Помогите понять в чём ошибка

Comment: Здесь нигде не указано, что именно `remove()` необходимо использовать. Поэтому причина для отметки дубликатом некорректная

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**не удаляйте из списка элементы когда двигаетесь направо по этому списку!!!**

а решение вашей задачи:

```
nums = [i for i in nums if i <= 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = [1,2,55,2,6,969,44,65,21,45,44,42,10,72,12,35,2,0,512,3,410,30]

print(list(filter(lambda x: x <= 30, nums)))
```

Comment: возвращает то же самое

Comment: скорее наоборот - ведь, как я понимаю, надо оставить элементы не превышающие 30